# What does IRP stand for?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

The Microsoft MASM language has an [IRP directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/irp). It's a synonym of the FOR directive which defines a "for each item" assembly loop.

I find the name perplexing. A search reveals nothing about the meaning of these 3 letters.

**What does IRP stand for?**

Comment: Indefinte RePeat

Comment: http://www.shsu.edu/~csc_tjm/spring2006/cs272/macros.html: "Another repetition macro is IRP (indefinite repeat)". That was the fourth link in the list when googling "irp directive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRP means Indefinite Repeat. This is a longstanding conventional name in assembly languages. It goes back to at least 1972.

The [MACRO-11 manual from June 1972](https://ia802703.us.archive.org/16/items/bitsavers_decpdp11doOSMACRO11AssemblerProgrammersManualJun72_5996682/DEC-11-OMACA-A-D_DOS_MACRO-11_Assembler_Programmers_Manual_Jun72.pdf) says:

> An indefinite repeat is essentially a macro definition which has only one dummy argument and is expanded for every real argument supplied.

The directive accepts a variable or *indefinite* number of items. Its body is repeated once for each item. The *dummy argument* takes on the value of the current item each iteration.

This contrasts with a simple repeat block which takes exactly 1 argument (a definite number of arguments) interpreted as a count and repeats the specified number of times.

Comment: Credit to @MichaelPetch for the useful comment that led to finding this.